How do i assign a column in my ArrayList to InetAddress?
I imported a csv file with 3 columns; "ipAddress", "name", "description" into my ArrayList. How do I create a method that pings just the "ipAddress" fields in my ArrayList ? Then how do I point my ArrayList at that method?
I have created a DataReader class to import the data and add it into my ArrayList. But I am now stuck on creating a method which I want to ping the ipAddress field in my ArrayList.

What do you mean by "ping"? What is your actual goal
?

The OP asked:

How do I create a method that pings just the "ipAddress" fields in my ArrayList?

Here is one way, presuming your OS has a ping method taking arguments. Just build a process using the supplied IP address and execute the process.  This version of ping comes with Windows.
String[] data = {"127.0.0.1","other","other"};
try {

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ping.exe", "-n", "1",
            "-w", "100", data[0]);

    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("Reply")) {
            System.out.println(line);
        } else if (line.startsWith("Request timed out")) {
            System.out.println("Request timed out for " + data[0]);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}


Bear in mind that failure to respond to ping does not necessarily mean the host Is offline. To advise properly we need to know the goal

@g00se. Of course. But where in the ops question or my answer did this imply the host was offline?  And using the local address was just for demonstration.

Sorry, I don't understand your question

@g00se  And I didn't understand your comment.  You said "Bear in mind that failure to respond to ping does not necessarily mean the host Is offline."   Why would I need to bear that in mind when that condition was never even mentioned.  The OP asked the following "How do I create a method that pings just the "ipAddress" fields in my ArrayList ?"  And I answered that.

And I didn't understand your comment. OK, it's straightforward. Since user24637246 is asking a question about a step instead of about the goal, I'm having to guess (which is why the question will likely be closed) what the goal is. Most often, people ping a host to see if it's up. That's my guess as to what the real goal is. You've provided code for a step, not a goal. Let's say you also think that's the goal (doesn't matter either way actually). What I'm saying is that pinging is not a reliable way to find out if the host's reachable unless you know it responds to ping.
